# How to get a WAV file duration in C?

Tags: c, windows, wav, getopenfilename

I'm writing a WAV Player in C with SIGIL API and windows.h library, I'm using GetOpenFileName from the windows.h library to open the file, and I need a way to the program "read" the duration of the WAV file, there is some function to do so?

Comment: I don't know if there's a API function for that, but this might be interesting to you http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Comment: [This too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075233/reading-and-processing-wav-file-data-in-c-c)

Comment: Isn't SIGIL something for e-books? Anyway, there is no function in standard C that tells you the duration of a WAV file. *If it is possible to approximate by dividing file length by a constant you want `fseek()` and `ftell()`*

Comment: @pmg there's an e-book reader, yes, but, there's also a library for user input, audio, image and user interface processing in C, [here](http://www.libsigil.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know:

**Time = [Size of file]/[Byte rate]**

You may also have some more factors:

- Frequency in cycles per second;
- Number of channels (1, 2, 4, 8...);
- A bit value (8, 16, etc.) determining the resolution per cycle;

This information should be in the header.

Comment: Yes, I've tought about it before, but, I didn't had a way to read that information, but, now with the comment from Frederico, I think I can do it, thanks.