# Reading subchunk2 data of a wav file in C++

Tags: c++, audio, wav

I am trying to read the data part of a .wav file into a buffer. I have already read the header part according to [C++ Reading the Data part of a WAV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660777/c-reading-the-data-part-of-a-wav-file)

Therefore, my file pointer `wavFile` now points to the beginning of the data section. Then I use the following code to read audio data into a buffer.

```
long bytes = wavHeader.bitsPerSample/8; 
long buffsize= wavHeader.Subchunk2Size/bytes;
int16_T *audiobuf = new int16_T[buffsize];
fread(audiobuf,bytes,buffsize,wavFile);
// do some processing
delete audiobuf;
```

In my test audio file, `bitsPerSample` is 16 and `Subchunk2Size` is 79844. Therefore, `buffsize` is 39922.

After running this code, I noticed that only first 256 positions of `audiobuf` get filled. But theoretically there should be 39922 entries of audio data. How can I sort out this issue?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you sure the wav file doesn't have the zeros in it? P.S. it should be `delete [] audiobuf;`

Comment: @jaket It does have some zeros but reads correctly upto 256 entries. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @Sam It is a single channel audio. I didn't try using `fstream` because I didn't find anything wrong with this code.