# How to Read Audio Files in C++

Tags: c++, audio, wav

So I basically want to write a program in C++ that takes in a .wav file (or any other uncompressed format for that matter) and returns sheet music. No problem with calculations provided that I learn how to actually get access to the time-pressure map. Is there any way to implement this without any fancy libraries? I just want it to be as simple as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Reading the Data part of a WAV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660777/c-reading-the-data-part-of-a-wav-file)

Comment: @rustyx well, that's the point on my project, do the FT and convert the result into sheet music

Comment: You can parse PCM-encoded WAV streams relatively easily, but the are many other encodings. So reading *any* WAV file wouldn't be feasible without a library. Here's an example with libavcodec: https://rodic.fr/blog/libavcodec-tutorial-decode-audio-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a library that isn't fancy. It is called "ffmpeg". Here is a c++ wrapper: https://github.com/Raveler/ffmpeg-cpp . You can leverage this powerful library to implement the solution.